# linked list create and display

Tags: c, function, linked-list

my linked list code is not printing the last node can you please help me where I am getting it wrong
I tried do while it didn't work
i don't want to make head node separate therefor please don't tell me change the whole code
how do i free allocated memory of the whole code
last how can i use recursion for display

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
int data ;
struct node *next;
}node;

 int create(int n);

 void display(node* head);

int main()
{
int n;
node* HEAD = NULL;
scanf("%d",&n);
HEAD=create(n);
display(HEAD);
return 0;
}

int create(int n)
{
int i;

node * head=NULL;
node * temp=NULL;
node * p = NULL;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    temp =(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    temp->next= NULL;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        p=head;
        while(p->next != NULL)
        {
            p=p->next;
        }
          p->next=temp;
      }
  }
  return head;
}

void display(node* head)
{
    node* p= head;

    while(p->next != NULL)
    {
    printf("\n data: %d",p->data);
    p=p->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about problems printing the last node, but consider what will be printed in display() for a list with only one element (i.e. when head->next == NULL).

Comment: You should really pay attention to messages emitted by the compiler. If it says "warning", it means you are doing something wrong and your computer is probably going to explode next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case of a single node linked list. Head->next would evaluate to NULL. And the value of Head would not be displayed. To remedy this move the printf statement up.

EDIT: YOU ALSO MUST ENSURE THAT HEAD IS NOT NULL, otherwise your code will still fail if you make my changes

```
void display(node* head)
{
    node* p= head;

    while(p->next != NULL)
    {
    printf("\n data: %d",p->data);
    p=p->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: see above answer, it considers the empty list edge case

Answer (score 1):

At the time the condition in the while loop fails, you still haven't checked the last node you're in. You dereferenced it at the end of the last iteration, but you never printed the data inside. A quick fix would be to just print the current node's data after the loop exits:

```
    while(p->next != NULL)
    {
       printf("\n data: %d",p->data);
       p=p->next;
    }
    printf("\n data: %d", p->data);
```

This would also fix the issue brought up in the comment on your question. Of course you still want to make sure that the list is not empty before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your while case, you need to change `while(p->next != NULL)` to `while(p != NULL)`.
The reason for this is because your pointer is on the last element but you are checking his next.
Another thing, change `int create(int n)` to `node * create(int n)`. You are returning pointer and not the `int` parameter.